# Using 2 verbs in a passive voice

Tags: voz-pasiva, se

You can use "se" to construct a passive voice sentence. The passive se formula is this:

se + verb (third person) + noun

Example:

> Se vende queso

English tranlation: Cheese sold here

Now I want to say "Only cheese may be sold here" in Spanish.
By using Dutch you could say: "Alleen kaas mag hier verkocht worden".

My question:
How can I use 2 verbs in the passive `se` formula?

Comment: Which two verbs are you referring to? In your request there is arguably one verb, "sell", or else three: "may" (a modal verb), "be" (an auxiliary) and "sell" (as its participle). There are a number of ways to express that meaning in Spanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the same way you would with one.  Note an active voice construction with and without *poder*

> *alguien vende queso*
>   *alguien puede vender queso*.

To use the *pasivo reflejo*, first obviously we remove the subject and make the main verb agree with *queso* (in this case, we change nothing, but if it were *quesos artesanales* or something, we'd get *pueden*).

> *vende<sub>(subj: queso)</sub> queso*
>   *puede<sub>(subj: queso)</sub> vender queso*

Finally, we add in the *se pasivo*.  This will generally (always? too lazy to look in the *Gramática*) go on the primary verb, be it modal or otherwise.

> ***se*** vende queso
>   ***se*** puede vender queso

Note that if the object is in the singular, it *can* also be interpreted (and very likely would be in the case of *se puede*) as a *se impersonal*, where English often uses the impersonal *you/one*.  The verb in that case will *always* be singular, regardless the object.

Comment: Thats interesting. I expected to use the word `sólo`. Why is `sólo` not necessary?

Comment: *Solo* (no accent) isn't actually part of the verb, so I didn't include is as part of my explanation (likewise I omitted *aquí*)